# Is there a way of hiding scrollbar track or making it transparent

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I only want to display the scrollbar thumb/paddle so it is on top of the page's background. I have tried giving the scrollbar track `Background: transparent;`,`display: none;` and  `visibility: hidden`.
I just want to know if there is a way of only displaying the scrollbar thumb/paddle.
[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/c6wno87k/1/

Comment: @UnknownPotato No, because they just made the scrollbar track's background white like the page's background, but its still there. If you made the page's background black, you would then be able to see it. I either want the scrollbar track to disappear or making it transparent so it gets the same background as the page's background image.

Comment: Looks like somebody else wanted this aswell,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634451/hide-scrollbar-track-but-show-scrollbar-thumb, hope somebody knows how to acheive this, wasn't able to help I'm afraid, possible that you need to aply javascript for this